# ASP.NET MVC Alter Markup before Output

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Excuse my limited knoweldge here.

In the past I have used Steve Sanderson's method to HTML encode by default at runtime: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/12/19/aspnet-mvc-prevent-xss-with-automatic-html-encoding/

I have a need to alter `img src` and `a href` attributes before they are spat out in the user's browser. There is a solution using JavaScript but this is not ideal for several reasons. Intercepting the compiler is not an option because of unnecessarily using `Response.Write` for trivial HTML.

Is there something I can do with HTTP modules or the view engine?

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** I do not need to HTML encode the attributes but I do have a need to change them.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [response filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx). Works with any ASP.NET project, including MVC. Should work even if you're using a different view engine, as it intercepts at a lower level.

Here's an actual example that strips whitespace:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx

I've used this before to rewrite links before sending to the client, but I can't find the code at the moment.

Comment: Better words for what I want to do - "rewrite links". Cheers!

Comment: A response filter was used to alter the markup before it was spat out. a HTTP module was used to kick off the response filter.